# String is not compatible

Tags: f#, printf

Not sure if I'm missing something right here, it's throwing an error when i try to print the url.

> Error string is not compatible with Printf.TextWriteFormat

```
type Credentials = {clientId: string; clientSecret: string}

let credentials = {clientId = ""; clientSecret = ""; deviceId = ""; deviceToken = ""}
let host = "https://example.com?grant_type=token";
let url = String.Format("%s?&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s", host, credentials.clientId, credentials.clientSecret)

printf url

let request = WebRequest.Create(url)
```

**Edit** Request header accept not working

```
    let request = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Method <- "POST"
    request.ContentType <- "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    //request.Headers.Set "Accept" "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    request.ContentLength <- (int64)data.Length


request.Accept <- "application/json;charset=UTF-8" // doesnt' work either
```

Comment: Ive had this same exact issue. The answer posted currently is the correct answer.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell casting fixed it `WebRequest.Create(url) :?> HttpWebRequest`

Comment: You don't need to cast it though. Just use a parameterized string. `printf "%s" url` should work. If not then use `%A`. It's much easier

Comment: I was referring to request.Accept problem which was pending from above question, otherwise my problem with stirng format was using commas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type that the first parameter of a `printf` function expects is not a `string`, it's rather a `TextWriterFormat<'T>` which can be derived from a literal string with format specifiers. This derivation is a compiler feature.

So you can solve it by adding a literal string with a format specifier for strings:

```
printf "%s" url
```

And for your last line you can use `sprintf` which returns the string, instead of printing it:

```
let url = sprintf "%s?&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s&device_id=%s&device_token=%s" host credentials.clientId credentials.clientSecret credentials.deviceId credentials.deviceToken
```

**EDIT**

This code works:

```
open System.Net

type Credentials = {clientId: string; clientSecret: string; deviceId: string; deviceToken: string}

let credentials = {clientId = "www.stackoverflow.com"; clientSecret = ""; deviceId = ""; deviceToken = ""}
let host = "https://example.com?grant_type=token";
let url = sprintf "%s?&client_id=%s&client_secret=%s" host credentials.clientId credentials.clientSecret

printf "%s" url

let request = WebRequest.Create(url)
```

Comment: i've several pieces of the string like device id and device token, can you have it concatenated in your result

Comment: thanks for edit. `WebRequest.Create(url)` has some error, see my edit please

Comment: `printf "%s" url` is giving me issue as well, error is expect types string but has string * string * string..

Comment: I added a small code that works. Hint: If you specify all the open namespaces in your questions, making the code fragment standalone/complete and the error easy to reproduce, it helps the person who answer to test your code and you can get better quality answers without going back and forth.

Comment: ok, my issue was putting commas between the vars in the url expression.

Comment: one last thing, can you help with how to specify Accept header in my request, see the edits please